# How to return object from MongoDb database in findOne method

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, return

sorry if it's easy mistake, I've not so much experience in JS, I've tried a lot of ways and I can't resolve this problem.

I can find and print my object from database, but I can't return it to my main method.

My main method (it's in another file than methods to database):

```
(async () => {
    try{
        const someClass = new SomeClass();
        const object = await someClass.database.getFirstObjectFromBase("collectionName");
        console.log(object);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
})();
```

and (before tries to debug this) my "object" is undefined.
Take a look on two methods I've used:

```
async connectAndReturnWithFunction(func) {
    return new Promise(
        function(resolve, reject){
            mongoClient.connect(url, {}, (error, client) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log("Cannot connect to db");
                } else {
                    console.log("Database connection established: " + dbname);
                };    
                const db = client.db(dbname);
                return func(db);
            }
        );
        }
    )
}
```

and last:

```
async getFirstObjectFromBase(collection) {
    return await this.connectAndReturnWithFunction(function(db) {
        return db.collection(collection)
        .findOne({}, function(err, result) {
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        })
    })
}
```

I tried something with 'then' too:

```
async getFirstObjectFromBase(collection) {
    return await this.connectAndReturnWithFunction(function(db) {
        return db.collection(collection)
        .findOne({})
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result); 
            return result;
        });
    })
}
```

In both examples of getFirstObjectFromBase console.log(result) print good object, but program just stop after this and I can't return this JSON to main method.

Thank you in advice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems in your code:

- Inside `connectAndReturnWithFunction` function, you never call `resolve()`
- `async` functions always return a `Promise`, so you don't need to create one yourself using the `Promise` constructor. You never use `await` keyword inside `connectAndReturnWithFunction` function, so making it `async` is unnecessary.
- Inside `connectAndReturnWithFunction` function, inside the the callback function of `mongoClient.connect`, in case of an error, you log a message indicating that connection to database couldn't be established but the last two lines of code

  ```
  const db = client.db(dbname);
  return func(db);
  ```

  will still execute. You probably meant to add those two lines inside the `else` block.

  ```
  mongoClient.connect(url, {}, (error, client) => {
      if (error) {
          console.log("Cannot connect to db");
      } else {
          console.log("Database connection established: " + dbname);

          const db = client.db(dbname);
          return func(db);
      }                 
  }
  ```

Reasone why `object` is undefined because inside the `connectAndReturnWithFunction`, you never call `resolve()`, which is needed to resolve the `Promise` with the data from the database.

To fix the problem, pass the `resolve()` and `reject()` functions to the callback function of `connectAndReturnWithFunction` function.

```
return func(db);
```

to

```
func(db, resolve, reject);
```

and inside the `getFirstObjectFromBase` function, call the `resolve()` function, passing in the `result` as an argument. In case of an error, call the `reject()` function, passing in the error object as an argument.

```
async getFirstObjectFromBase(collection) {
   return this.connectAndReturnWithFunction(function(db, resolve, reject) {
       return db.collection(collection)
         .findOne({}, function(err, result) {
             if (err) {
                reject(err);
             } else {
                resolve(result);
             }
         })
   })
}
```

Comment: Oh It was so easy.
Thank you so much, it works.

Comment: I've wrote previous comment before your edit. I've learned really a lot from your answer, thanks!